# How google Analytics detect android device

Tags: javascript, android, google-analytics, client-hints

I know GA using UserAgent string to detect device id or brand name for an android device. But i wonder do Google using [WURLF library](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or they building and device's useragent database for themselves.

Because our company has an android device that update user agent to  WURLF  but in GA, it's still not set.

Comment: User Agent is never reliable. In fact, some Android devices pretend they are iPhones!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my question is not focus to user-agent,i wonder how GA detect android,using WURLF library or their database. Because as i said, our device has relized brand-name by WURLF, but in GA, it's still not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at your user agent data in OpenDDR?

These slides talk about where Google is looking to go with acquiring mobile meta data and a proposal for using [Client-Hints](http://bit.ly/client-hints-w3cperf)

However, as far as I can tell in web analytics, devices/browsers that don't have identifying UA strings are simply not going to be counted by web analytics companies, and hence not catered for.

Some somewhat relevant discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.compatibility/Qx9zMwJesJA).

Comment: Thanks Zatch_rulz, does anyone has more infomation for me ?